# Upgrading RAM in HP Compaq d530

Tags: ddr, sdram

I want to upgrade my hp compaq d530 from 1.2GB to 4GB of RAM. I look at the specs: http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/11632_ca/11632_ca.html and saw that I could get up to 4GB of RAM that is DDR, PC3200. So, I got 4GB of RAM. I ordered 4 of these http://www.ebay.com/itm/190398777195?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649.

When I installed all 4 I get 5 beeps and 5 red blinks which I've concluded means I'm having a memory problem. When I switch back to 1.2 GB it works fine. I was wondering, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

How did you have 1.2GB of RAM in there?

Crucial says you can install 1 chip at a time
http://www.crucial.com/upgrade/HP+-+Compaq-memory/HP+Business+Desktops/D530+Series+All+Form+Factors-upgrades.html

Have you tried putting one chip at a time in there to see if you happened to get a bad RAM chip?

I assume you checked all the RAM chips to make sure they were the size and spec you were expecting.

Comment: The stickers say that they are what I ordered. When I try putting in 1GB, it does the same beeping.

Comment: tryed 1 at a time and got the same problem with each chip

Comment: IDK how I had 1.2 GB it just says I do The Ram that is in there is unlabeled

Answer (score 0):

All the specs of the memory modules are correct, so it's possible that one is broken.

download and burn [The ultimate boot cd](http://www.winsoftware.de/Startedownload47349).

Try to put the old and the new memory in, so the system has a chance to start. (The only reason it's not smart to do this, is because the faster RAM modules will be downclocked to the slower frequency)

And try to use the check memory feature in The ultimate boot cd.

Good luck!